# why the <core-iconset> can be used without "import" in polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, frontend

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>core-icon-button</title>

  <script src="../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

  <link rel="import" href="core-icon-button.html">
  <style>
  </style>

</head>

<body unresolved>


<template is="auto-binding">
    <template repeat="{{icon in $.meta.metaData.icons.iconNames}}">
      <core-icon-button icon="{{icon}}" title="{{icon}}"></core-icon-button>
    </template>
    <core-icon-button icon="menu"><span>label</span></core-icon-button>
  </div>
  <core-iconset id="meta"></core-iconset>
</template>

</body>
</html>
```

Please can someone explain to me,why the core-iconset element can be used without "import"?
sorry for my poor english.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take a look at the [core-icon-button.html](https://github.com/Polymer/core-icon-button/blob/master/core-icon-button.html) file, at the top we find the following two lines:

```
<link rel="import" href="../core-icon/core-icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="../core-icons/core-icons.html">
```

and [core-icon](https://github.com/Polymer/core-icon/blob/master/core-icon.html) in turn imports [core-iconset](https://github.com/Polymer/core-iconset/blob/master/core-iconset.html):

```
<link rel="import" href="../core-iconset/core-iconset.html">
```

So core-iconset.html gets imported via this chain of imports.

Each element imports all the other elements that it needs, such that the client of an element is not responsible for importing the dependencies. And since these imports (more precisely: the element registrations) are global (and not scoped to the importing element), you can use these elements anywhere after they got imported.